# Como usar onActivityResult quando há mais de um startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Preciso verificar o estado do usuário *yes* ou *no*, ao solicitar o bluetooth. Só que eu já uso o mesmo método para o reconhecimento de voz.

Segue o meu código:

```java
package com.example.audio_auto;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioActivity extends Activity{

    public Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private final static int VOICE_RESULT = 1;
    protected static final int Request_Enable_bt = 0;
    private ImageButton btnSpeack;
    private Button btSair, connect, enviar;
    private TextView txtText, txt;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    int counter;
    private static final String TAG = "QuickNotesMainActivity"; 
    BluetoothDevice mDevice;// cria uma conecao com o dispositivo e consulta.
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket mSocket; // gerencia a conexao
    Thread workerThread;
    OutputStream mOutputStream;
    InputStream mInputStream;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);

        enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btSair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnSpeack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);



        btnSpeack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        "Favor falar no microfone");

                try {

                    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RESULT);
                    txtText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    txtText.setText("");
                    // verifica();

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "nao suporta seu dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }

            }

        });

        btSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    closeBT();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void closeBT()throws IOException{
                stopWorker = true;
                mOutputStream.close();
                mInputStream.close();
                mSocket.close();

            }
        });

        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nao tem suporte bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){

                    tornaVisivel();
                    Log.i(TAG,"nao espera o resultado!");

            }

            else 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O bluetooth esta conectado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   

        });


        enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    protected void tornaVisivel() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                                                                     
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
         BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); // emite um pedido para ativar bluetooth
          startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);

    }

    protected void Conectar() {

        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){ // verifica se esta abilitado
            Log.i(TAG," bluetooth!");
            pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); //checando a lista de aparelhos emparelhados              
            Log.i(TAG,"Found [" + pairedDevices.size() + "] devices."); 
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) { // se tiver lista de aparelhos emparelhados
                Log.i(TAG,"pareou");
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) { // atribui as lista de aparelhos pareados no device do tipo BluetoothDevice
                    if (device.getName().equals("SL4 professional")) // pega o nome do dispositivo bluetooth e compara com a string
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG,"ok bluetooth!");
                        mDevice = device; //atribui o nome comparado com a string e coloca em mDevice
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == BT_ATIVAR){
      if (RESULT_OK == resultCode){
        // SIM
      } else {
        // NÃO
      }
    }
 }


//////////////////////////////////////  

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == VOICE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtText.setText(matches.get(0).toString());
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String[] confirmar = { "bola", "dado" };

        for (int i = 0; i < confirmar.length; i++) {

            if (txtText.getText().toString().contains(confirmar[i])) {

                txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                txt.setText("Comando Conhecido");
                break;
            } else {
                txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                txt.setText("Comando Desconhecido !");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi nada da sua pergunta. Qual é o seu problema?

Comment: se foi o que eu entendi, pesquisa sobre "Polimorfismo".  acho que é isso que pretendes.

Comment: entao eu tenho dois metodos onActivityResult () meu app quando pede ativacao bluetooth pelo usuario eu preciso saber se ele clikou sim ou não para eu dar continuidade na meu app só que para eu saber disso pela documentacao o resultado vai para esse metodo "onActivityResult()" só que ja estou usando ele para o comando de voz logo abaixo e por isso da o erro methodo duplicate ! entendeu ?

Comment: outra coisa pessoal tem algum tutorial explicando como formatar as perguntas e o cod ! pois quando posto aqui alguma duvida, fica tudo sem formato ! acho que alguem de vcis arruma por isso que fica legalzinho .. obrigado

Comment: Veja [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/2541) como formatar as publicações

Comment: valeu ramaral agora esta formatado direito...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só pode haver um método `onActivityResult()` em cada *Activity*.

Esse método é chamado na sequência de cada chamada a `startActivityForResult`.
Ao chamar o método `startActivityForResult` é passado, no segundo parâmetro, um *requestCode*.

Esse *requestCode* é recebido no método `onActivityResult()`.
Basta verificar qual é esse *requestCode* e atuar em conformidade.

Olhando o seu código, você usa `VOICE_RESULT` para o *requestCode* quando usa `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` e 0 quando usa o `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE`.

Assim, o seu método `onActivityResult` deverá ser qualquer coisa como:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == VOICE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       //Fazer o que pretende quando retorna do Voice
    }
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Fazer o que pretende quando retorna do Bluetooth
    }
}
```

Em vez de 0 use a constante Request_Enable_bt, definida no início do código, para o *requestCode* do Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Ramaral ! na verdade eu percebi isso antes de vc postar mas foi exatamente o que fiz valeu mano resolveu meu problema e o melhor minha duvida (que só pode uma vez esse metodo ) segue meu cod:

```
package com.example.audio_auto;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AudioActivity extends Activity{    
public Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
private final static int VOICE_RESULT = 1;
protected static final int Request_Enable_bt = 0;
private ImageButton btnSpeack;
private Button btSair, connect, enviar;
private TextView txtText, txt;
volatile boolean stopWorker;
byte[] readBuffer;
int readBufferPosition;
int counter;
private static final String TAG = "QuickNotesMainActivity"; 
BluetoothDevice mDevice;// cria uma conecao com o dispositivo e consulta.
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mSocket; // gerencia a conexao
Thread workerThread;
OutputStream mOutputStream;
InputStream mInputStream;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
    enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btSair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnSpeack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    btnSpeack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                    "Favor falar no microfone");

            try {

                startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RESULT);
                txtText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                txtText.setText("");
                // verifica();

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "nao suporta seu dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }

        }

    });

    btSair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                closeBT();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void closeBT()throws IOException{
            stopWorker = true;
            mOutputStream.close();
            mInputStream.close();
            mSocket.close();            
        }
    });

    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nao tem suporte bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){

                tornaVisivel();
                Log.i(TAG,"nao espera o resultado!");               
        }

        else 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O bluetooth esta conectado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }   

    });


    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

protected void tornaVisivel() {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();                                                                     
    Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
     BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE); // emite um pedido para ativar bluetooth
      startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);

}

protected void Conectar() {

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){ // verifica se esta abilitado
        Log.i(TAG," bluetooth!");
        pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(); //checando a lista de aparelhos emparelhados              
        Log.i(TAG,"Found [" + pairedDevices.size() + "] devices."); 
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) { // se tiver lista de aparelhos emparelhados
            Log.i(TAG,"pareou");
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) { // atribui as lista de aparelhos pareados no device do tipo BluetoothDevice
                if (device.getName().equals("SL4 professional")) // pega o nome do dispositivo bluetooth e compara com a string
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,"ok bluetooth!");
                    mDevice = device; //atribui o nome comparado com a string e coloca em mDevice
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    case 0:

              if (RESULT_OK == resultCode){
           Log.i(TAG,"sim ativo");
              } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"nao ativo");
              }

        break;// break 0

    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtText.setText(matches.get(0).toString());

        String[] confirmar = { "bola", "dado" };

        for (int i = 0; i < confirmar.length; i++) {

            if (txtText.getText().toString().contains(confirmar[i])) {

                txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                txt.setText("Comando Conhecido");
                break;
            } else {
                txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                txt.setText("Comando Desconhecido !");
            }
         }
        }
        break;// break 1    
    }

 }
}
```