# Receber parametros de diferentes activity e somar

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Olá,

Preciso passar os parâmetros de duas telas para a **tela_inicio**, seja os parâmetros "SALDO" da tela **saldo** onde será passado para uma EditText (lblSaldoAtual) na **tela_inicio** e em seguida pegar um valor posto em "EXTRA" na tela **acrescentarsaldo** e somar ao parâmetro "SALDO" e mostrar na lblSaldoAtual na tela **tela_inicio**

Ajuda por favor
Obrigado.

**TELA tela_inicio**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_inicio);

    lblSaldoAtual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSaldoAtual);
    btnSaldo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaldo);
    lblSaldoTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSaldoTotal);
    btnMenos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);
    bMais = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMais);
    bMenos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMenos);

    btnSaldo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMenos.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMais.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMenos.setOnClickListener(this);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Classe1 classe = new Classe1();
    classe.recebesaldo();
    classe.recebeextra();
}

class Classe1 {
    Double extra, saldoatual, saldototal, total;
    public void recebesaldo() {
        Intent it = getIntent();
        if (it != null) {
            Bundle b1 = it.getExtras();
                saldoatual = Double.parseDouble(b1.getString("SALDO"));
                lblSaldoAtual.setText(Double.toString(saldoatual));
                saldototal = Double.parseDouble(b1.getString("SALDO"));
                lblSaldoTotal.setText(Double.toString(saldototal));

            }
        }
   public void recebeextra() {
                Intent it2 = getIntent();
                extra = Double.parseDouble(it2.getStringExtra("EXTRA"));
                total = extra + saldoatual;
                lblSaldoAtual.setText(Double.toString(total));
   }
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnSaldo) {
        Intent it = new Intent(this, saldo.class);
        startActivity(it);}
      else if (view == bMais) {
        Intent it = new Intent(this, acrescentarsaldo.class);
        startActivity(it);
    } else if (view == bMenos) {
        Intent it = new Intent(this, acrescentarsaldo.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

**TELA acrescentarsaldo**

```
public class acrescentarsaldo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button btnOK;
    private EditText txtAcrescentarSaldo;
    public static String acrescenta;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acrescentarsaldo);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        txtAcrescentarSaldo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAcrescentarSaldo);

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(acrescentarsaldo.this);

    }
    public static String getAcrescenta(){
        return acrescenta;

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it = new Intent(acrescentarsaldo.this, tela_inicio.class);
        it.putExtra("EXTRA", txtAcrescentarSaldo.getText().toString());
        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

**TELA saldo**

```
public class saldo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText txtAtualizar;
    private Button btnAtualizar;
    private static String saldo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saldo);
        btnAtualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAtualizar);
        txtAtualizar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAtualizar);

        btnAtualizar.setOnClickListener(saldo.this);
    }
    public static String getSaldo(){
        return saldo;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent it = new Intent(saldo.this, tela_inicio.class);
        it.putExtra("SALDO", txtAtualizar.getText().toString());
        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja se é [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50787/2541) o que procura.

Comment: Não, não consegui usar desta forma

Comment: Terá de explicar melhor pois não está claro o que quer.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero ter sido mais claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas com este código fica difícil entender o que realmente "*não está funcionando*".

Qual valor está sendo exibido para você no `textView` **lblSaldoAtual**?

Está passando para a `Intent` de chamada desta `Activity` os valores corretamente? Por exemplo:

```
intent.putExtra("SALDO", "5000");
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", "200");
```

Fiquei em dúvida na condição:

```
if (lblSaldoAtual != null) {
```

O código está rodando em loop? a primeira vez vazia e a segunda preenchida?

Eu recomendo a você inserir Logs no código, ou rodar no mode debug para encontrar onde ele está caindo. E identificar se as variáveis que estão sendo declaradas no início da `Classe1` (`Double extra, saldoatual, saldototal, total;`) estão sendo inicializadas ao criar um novo objeto com a linha `Classe1 classe = new Classe1();` ?

Alguns adendos:

Tudo este código está sendo chamado dentro do `onCreate`?

Evite declarar 2 vezes uma variável com o mesmo nome, igual ao `Double extra`.

----------------**Nova Resposta**--------------------

Quando se utiliza o [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) ao transitar de tela em tela, necessitamos passar todos os valores. O que está ocorrendo é que o "SALDO" está sendo zerada após a chamada do `acrescentarsaldo`.

Você precisará incluir no `onClick` das chamadas ao `acrescentarsaldo` o valor do Saldo:

```
it.putExtra("SALDO", lblSaldoAtual.getText().toString());
```

antes do `startActivity(it);`

Uma observação, adicione o comando `finish();` para evitar que fiquem com inúmeras activities abertas.

Você precisará inserir no `acrescentarsaldo`:

```
private String saldo;
```

dentro de `onCreate`:

```
saldo = getIntent().getStringExtra("SALDO");
```

e no retorno para `tela_inicial`:

```
it.putExtra("SALDO", saldo);
```

Apenas para concluir, utilize `try catches` nas partes do código onde você converte `String` para `Double`, para evitar que a aplicação quebre.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Editei a pergunta, espero ter sido mais claro. Quanto ao `if (lblSaldoAtual != null) {` eu estava efetuando testes e acabei deixando passar. E quando eu rodo por debug, a impressão que tenho é que está executando as duas Intent ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Editei minha resposta, pode começar a partir de **Nova Resposta**. Att

Comment: Mais uma dúvida, qual seria o método certo de passar todas essas variaveis para Double? A forma que usei está de acordo?

Comment: O método está correto, sim! Um coisa bacana de se fazer é transformar virgula em pontos, ficando assim: `Double.parseDouble(var.replace(",", "."))` . Nunca se sabe o que o usuário irá digitar. Você também pode retirar espaços para ter certeza que a transformação da `String` não "quebre" a aplicação.